# why google is not charging me for google API usage

Tags: google-maps

I using map place api, gecoding api and direction api in my app. For two months already see the photos below. But haven't got charged for any money. Why is that?

[image]

Comment: Because you are using less than the ($200) credit?

Comment: they gave us $200 credit ?

Comment: yes  $200  each month

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the analytics shows, you haven't crossed 11500 `Places API` calls or 40000 `Directions API` call. Google Maps now provides $200 free monthly usage. Head over to this [link](https://cloud.google.com/maps-platform/pricing) to know the number of requests per API your monthly $200 free credit can support. Also, add daily quota to restrict the usage.